# Can I save a RandStream and load it at a later time to continue a simulation?

Tags: matlab, random

My question is whether a `RandStream` in MATLAB can be saved to a file and loaded at a later time to continue a simulation picking up the random number sequence from it's last point. All I can find is that one can save a `RandStream`, e.g:

```
s1 = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',1); 
savedState = s1.State;
```

Nothing about saving a stream to a file and loading it at another run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the random number generator's state to a MAT-file using the `save` function. The `load` function will load it back in. For example:

```matlab
> s1 = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',145);
> state = s1.State;
> s1.rand(1,4)
ans =
    0.2830    0.0020    0.5306    0.0804
> s1.State = state;
> s1.rand(1,4)
ans =
    0.2830    0.0020    0.5306    0.0804
> save MyRandState state
```

Now, after a `clear all`, or in a new MATLAB session:

```matlab
> load MyRandState
> s1 = RandStream('mt19937ar');
> s1.State = state;
> s1.rand(1,4)
ans =
    0.2830    0.0020    0.5306    0.0804
```

---

However, it is even easier to save your whole random number generator object to a MAT-file:

```matlab
> s1 = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',145);
> save MyRandState s1
> s1.rand(1,4)
ans =
    0.2830    0.0020    0.5306    0.0804
> clear all
> load MyRandState
> s1.rand(1,4)
ans =
    0.2830    0.0020    0.5306    0.0804
```